# Insert blank VBA variable into SQL decimal(x,y) field as Null

Tags: vba, excel, adodb, sql-server-2014-express

I have a ADODB command in Excel 2013 VBA to execute a Insert string in a table where some fields are Decimal(x,y) in my SQL Server 2014. I'm having problems when my excel cell is empty to insert it as NULL into SQL.

ie.

VBA Code:

Lets say variable **sPrice** can point to an empty excel cell.

```
sDate = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
sPrice = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
sQuantity = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
```

And the argument of my Insert lets say:

```
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prices] ([date], [Price], [Quantity])
              values ('" & SDate & "', " & sPrice & ",'" & sQuantity & "')"
```

note in SQL data types are:

```
[date] Datetime
[Price] Deciaml(28,12)
[Quantity] Real
```

So I not including double single quote for sPrice as it's a Decimal.
thanks,

Comment: *I'm having problems* is not a useful description. What specific *problems* are you having?

Comment: if sPrice is declared as a double, a blank cell value will parse as 0

Comment: SQL server do not accept a empty (,    ,)  in the insert command for a Decimal field

Comment: I need it to be NULL not zero in DB

Comment: Your database is expecting a decimal, and you want to insert a null if the decimal value is 0?  Have I got that right?

Comment: I want to insert NULL in a decimal SQL field when my VBA variable is blank.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix you could do would be to change the value of sPrice to "NULL" if its value is =0

```
sDate = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
sPrice = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
sQuantity = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)

If sPrice = 0 Then
    sPrice = "NULL"
End If

conn.Execute "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prices] ([date], [Price], [Quantity])
              values ('" & SDate & "', " & sPrice & ",'" & sQuantity & "')"
```

I'm not sure if a string containing "NULL" is what you're looking for, but you can change sPrice = "NULL" to whichever value your SQL DB will accept as a NULL Value

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think my case should use IsEmpty(value) ? Since my cell have no value. And in My real code a have many variables to check, how do I loop check who is empty and if so set to NULL ?

Comment: If you loop through your iRowNo, you can add a condition like:

If Cells(iRowNo, 1).value = vbNullString Then
    myvar = "NULL"
Else
    myvar = Cells(iRowNo, 1).value
End If